# Bootstrap container not see-thru?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fullscreen Bootstrap container that's sitting in front of a color overlay I added. But it seems that the container blocks the overlay even though it is mostly empty, why is that so? I need it behind my container as the img inside the container needs to be on top of the color. The html's body's color is coming through, though. But I need both the html's body color and also the overlay to be seperate as I'm slowly fading the overlay out to show the body color... Wondering if it sounds confusing. =x Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-xs-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-xs-center">
            <img src="../img/cover_coral.png" id="myCover">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myOverlay"></div>
```

Comment: If you could provide the CSS as well, it will be easier for us to reproduce and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap's `container-fluid` class will cause your `div` tag to span the width of the page (with a bit of padding applied).  If you have an overlay you want to show in front of it, your best option is to use CSS to add a `z-index` of say 2000 (any large number will do).  When you fade out, simply animate the opacity of the overlay and/or change the z-index so it's behind the container.

Comment: I tried using z-index but it doesn't work though. And also if it did work, won't it cover up the img I have in the container?

Comment: Yes, but your image is inside the container.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the overlay?  Set a low z-index on the container, a high z-index on the overlay, and an even higher z-index on the image if you want them layered like that.